# How to create centralized cognito jwt validation for microservices

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I have four microservices users, cohorts, schemes, and booking and I am using cognito for login functionality, where can i validate jwt token generated by cognito do I have to validate in every microservices(seems repetitive coding) or is there a way to host the validation in lamda and redirect jwt is verified (if yes please tell me how to do it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This somewhat depends on if your microservices are each exposed to the internet or proxied behind an API Gateway or Load Balancer.

- Amazon API Gateway REST APIs can [Use API Gateway Lambda authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html)
- Amazon API Gateway HTTP APIs have [Lambda authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html) and [JWT authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html)
- Application Load Balancers can [authenticate users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html) using Amazon Cognito user pools

If your microservices are exposed to the internet or you are implementing a zero trust network, then you may want to validate on each use. Look at a library like [AWS JWT Verify](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify) which can verify any JWT, but has a `CognitoJwtVerifier` that allows for easier configuration using Cognito specific parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use API Gateway and JWT or Lambda Authorizer to validate tokens in a centralized way.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html